# Azure DevOps Pipeline not downloading reference

Tags: azure-devops

I'm relatively new to Azure DevOps, but I've already created 4 other pipelines that are working. I'm running into trouble with a build pipeline that is not pulling in NuGet references. I added the Task NuGet restore, but it's only getting some of the packages.

It works when I build in Visual Studio 2017. If I do a nuget restore from the command line, some of the packages are fetched. When I build, Visual Studio fetches the additional packages at the beginning of the build. Why is the NuGet restore task not fetching all of the packages? Why are the remaining packages fetched during the Visual Studio build, but not during the Azure DevOps build?

My project is old legacy ASP.NET that my boss wants automated. I'm talking the version of ASP.NET with .ASPX files that preceded MVC.

This is the error from the Azure DevOps build:

### [error]WebApp\web.config(95,0): Error ASPCONFIG: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue finally? I am running into the same situation

Answer (score 0):

For this issue , first, make sure to select `vs2017-win2016` agent when running the pipeline.

[image]

Secondly you can try to install the latest nuget.

[image]

Another possibility for your issue could be that some packages used by your project is not hosted in nuget.org. If part of the packages used locally are hosted in private server or local package source, the online Nuget Restore Task can't download the mssing packages. Please check your packages.config and project file to make sure all your packages are hosted in nuget.org.

Comment: I was already using vs2017. As you suggested, I tried NuGet 5.5, but that didn't work either. I've also tried going back to older versions. The missing reference is noted in the error message - Microsoft.ReportView.Common - which is on nuget.org.

Comment: Can you share some details about your project type? Is that a .NET core project or .NET framework project, if that's one .NET core project, try using dotnet restore command in [Net Core task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops)

Comment: It is legacy ASP.NET. This is the version of ASP.NET prior to MVC that use .ASPX files.

Comment: I tested that with a old MVC web project from VS2015, but it all worked well on my side with all necessary packages are downloaded. Can you share some details in your question to show how you define the tasks in the pipeline? And it could be better if you can share the log of your restore task and build task using GitHub, so that I could check it directly for you! Note: Delete any personal info before sharing the log.

Comment: Tasks: Get sources, Agent Job 1, Nuget version 4.x,  Nuget restore, Build Solution. The build solution step fails. I don't know how to upload the error log.

Comment: The Nuget restore task is passing and says, "All packages listed in packages.config are already installed." So I'm not sure why I'm getting missing reference errors.